# " Can't use function return value in write context in line 36 " error in PHP

Tags: php

I was coding in PHP and this weird error pops out.

```
if(isset($_GET["failauth"])){ ?>
    <div>Sorry, your user name or password is not correct. Please re-enter. </div>
    <form id="loginform" action="login.php" method="post">
<?php } 
else if(isset($_GET("usernotexist"))){ ?>
    <div>Sorry, the username is not found</div>
    <form id="signupform" action="login.php?signup=true" method="get">
<?php }     
else { ?>
    <form id="loginform" action="login.php" method="post">
<?php } ?>
        <div><input name="name" type="text" size="8" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="/^.{3,8}$/" /> <strong>User Name</strong></div>
        <div><input name="password" type="password" size="8" pattern="/^[0-9].{4,10}[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/" /> <strong>Password</strong></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></div>
    </form>
```

Line 36 refers to the "else if" statement. I am curious why it pasts the first one but did not pass the else if part? Is it has something to do with the syntax cause I have never used else if statement before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_GET("usernotexist")`

should be:

`$_GET["usernotexist"]`

Comment: Just to add some context: $_GET uses [] brackets because it is an array of values, not a method, which uses () parenthesis.

Comment: Yes and although it was a typo, using a function return value where it expects a variable would also cause the same message, such as `empty($this->doSomething())`